# Blade guard won't lift

Tags: saw

[image][image][image]I own a King 10" mitre saw. The blade guard won't retract when I lower the saw blade to make a cut.
The manufacturer has discontinued replacement blade guards.
What I discovered is there are several plastic pins that set the position of the inside plate of the guard that have broken due to fatigue. I don't think there are pop rivets that small to hold the plate in the right position.
If I can get the proper setting for that plate, would expoxy glue suffice (to take the place of the broken off pins)?

Comment: Any way to include a few pictures so we can see what you discovered?

Comment: Maybe small split pins? Pics would definitely help

Comment: Pics would _definitely_ help out. If you don't get a good answer here (and you might), you may consider asking at [woodworking.se], as there is a lot of tool knowledge there, too. I don't, however, think epoxy would _take the place of_ the plastic pins - you'd have a heck of a time forming it properly. It _may_ however, hold the pins back in place (or some sort of replacement if the originals have been lost in the dust collector).

Comment: Pics added. After looking closer at the holes where the plastic pins should be, I may be able to use a small pop rivet.

Comment: Upon closer examination, I think mixing some epoxy glue and filling those voids where the 4 plastic pins should be, once I line them up, would solve my issue. I just reinstalled the blade guard with the plate in the correct position and the guard raises when I lower the blade.